# Timer App closing out after second onClick of the START button

Tags: android, android-fragments, timer, timertask

I am pretty new to android and am making a timer app (The code is not complete, as you can see, but I am testing on thing at a time).  hitting the start button a second time results in the app closing out. I edited my code so that the timer is being recreated each call to onClick, but the app still closes out after the second click. Thank you for the help.

```
package com.example.ryan.timerapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    secondsView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.seconds);
    tenSecondsView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tensSeconds);
    hoursView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hours);
    tenHoursView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tensHours);
    minutesView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.minutes);
    tenMinutesView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tensMinutes);

       timer = new Timer();

}

 TextView secondsView;
 TextView tenSecondsView;
 TextView hoursView;
 TextView tenHoursView;
 TextView minutesView;
 TextView tenMinutesView;

    Timer timer;
    TimerTask timerTask;


    public void start(View view){

        if(timer != null) {
            timerTask.cancel();
            timer.cancel();
        }
        timer = new Timer();
         timerTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                runOnUiThread(new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        int secondsInt = Integer.parseInt(secondsView.getText().toString());

                        int tenSecondsInt = Integer.parseInt(tenSecondsView.getText().toString());

                        int hoursInt = Integer.parseInt(hoursView.getText().toString());

                        int tenHoursInt = Integer.parseInt(tenHoursView.getText().toString());

                        int minutesInt = Integer.parseInt(minutesView.getText().toString());

                        int tenMinutesInt = Integer.parseInt(tenMinutesView.getText().toString());
                        if (secondsInt < 9) {
                            secondsInt++;
                            secondsView.setText(secondsInt + "");
                        } else {
                            secondsInt = 0;
                            secondsView.setText(secondsInt + "");
                            if (tenSecondsInt < 6) {
                                tenSecondsInt++;
                                tenSecondsView.setText(tenSecondsInt + "");
                            } else {
                                tenSecondsInt = 0;
                                tenSecondsView.setText(tenSecondsInt + "");
                                if (minutesInt < 9) {
                                    minutesInt++;
                                    minutesView.setText(minutesInt + "");
                                } else {
                                    minutesInt = 0;
                                    minutesView.setText(minutesInt + "");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }));

            }
        };
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask,0, 1000);

    }



public void stop(View view){
    timer.cancel();
}

public void reset(View view){

    secondsView.setText("0");
    tenSecondsView.setText("0");

    minutesView.setText("0");

    tenMinutesView.setText("0");

    hoursView.setText("0");

    tenHoursView.setText("0");

}


}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.ryan.timerapp.MainActivity"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:text="Timer"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tensHours"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="35sp"
            android:text="0"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hours"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="35sp"
            android:text="0"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/firstColon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="35sp"
            android:text=":"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tensMinutes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="35sp"
            android:text="0"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/minutes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="35sp"
            android:text="0"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/secondColon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:text=":"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tensSeconds"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="35sp"
            android:text="0"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/seconds"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="35sp"
            android:text="0"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:text="START"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:onClick="start"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stopButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:text="STOP"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:onClick="stop"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/resetButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:text="RESET"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:onClick="reset"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post the XML file so I can try to re-create this?

Comment: I posted it but the top of the xml says this:    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.ryan.timerapp.MainActivity"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    >

Comment: it would not show that, but that is there

Comment: Cut and paste the XML into a separate code segment instead of being bundled with java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the first being the Seconds counter not updating past 1 second

`TimerTask` is used to run a particular task at a specified time.
`timer.schedule()` is not meant to run continuously. 
Check this [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html#schedule(java.util.TimerTask,%20java.util.Date)).
So this block of code-

```
 int secondsInt = Integer.parseInt(txt.getText().toString()); 
                    secondsInt++;

                    if(secondsInt<=6) {
                        txt.setText(secondsInt + "");
                    }
```

will run only once . Hence

> Seconds counter not updating past 1 second

is the apparent behavior.

> hitting the start button a second time results in the app closing out

You are trying to run an already scheduled `TimerTask`.
You need to create a new `Timer` instance to start your `TimerTask` again.

Change your start() method -

```
public void start(View view){

        if(timer != null) {
                    timerTask.cancel();
                    timer.cancel();
                }
                timer = new Timer();
                timerTask = new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        runOnUiThread(new Thread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                int secondsInt = Integer.parseInt(txt.getText().toString());
                                secondsInt++;

                                if(secondsInt<=6) {
                                    seconds.setText(secondsInt + "");
                                }
                            }
                        }));

                    }
                };
                timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask,0, 1000);

    }
```

Also, no need to initialize your TextView again and again . Do it once only in `onCreate()` -

```
private TextView seconds; 
  private Timer timer;
  private TimerTask timerTask;
```

In onCreate()

```
seconds = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.seconds);
```

Comment: I created the new Instance and everything works for the first start/pause/reset. after that, when the start button gets clicked it closes out

Comment: I updated my code, but an error is being thrown at line 47, in the timeTask.cancel(); line

Comment: the error is: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick (error located on line 47)

Comment: You are writing  TimerTask timerTask = { in start() but my code has  timerTask = new TimerTask() . Please copy my code. Declare  timerTask outside private TimerTask timerTask; It will definitely work.

Comment: Remove 
       timer = new Timer(); from onCreate()